# How can I challenge previous arenas?

Tags: clash-royale

I've advanced to Arena 2, but I don't see an option to go back to previous arenas in order to continue collecting the previous chests. How can I go back to previous arenas? If it's not possible, how can I collect the cards from the previous arenas?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of: [Do higher Arena chests contain any lower Arena Rares and Epics?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/257392/4797)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to go back for that. [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257394/80141) answer states that you'll get lower arena cards in higher tiered arenas.

The reason that you cannot go back, is that you have to fight opponents in the same league as you. Otherwise you'll outclass your opponents,which wouldn't be fun for the both of you.

Answer (score 0):

As Mathias711 stated in [his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257706/120054), you don't need to go back to collect previous chests. When you finish a battle, you are awarded the chest for the arena that you are currently in. The chests from higher arenas contain more cards, and contain cards from previous arenas.

If you are unable to stay above the trophy threshold for an arena, you will fall back down to the previous one. At that point, victories will award those chests instead.

Finally, I'd like to mention that when you are near a trophy threshold you may be matched up against players that are in a different arena than you, and you may be battling in their arena, instead of your own. This can award you chests of that level without being in that arena.<sup>[1](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Arenas)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you drop your trophies enough you'll be demoted to the previous arena.

I didn't get the prince and I'm hoping not having an unecessary higher tier common card in my chests will increase my chance to get the prince or witch

Comment: It seems getting those cards becomes easier as you get higher. I often get witches in Arena 3.

Comment: Since I've seen folks speculating about what I call the "Goblin Stadium Exploit" all over the web, I decided to [**math out the pros and cons**](https://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/the-most-controversial-clash-royale-exploit/).  Other than what I'd consider a slight odds benefit for buying Epics in the Shop, you are better off climbing.  You'll have more fun that way too...

Answer (score -3):

you should start a battle and let the opponent three crown you. by doing this you lose trophies and can go back to lower arenas. This reduces the number of cards in the shop